# Kafka adminclient API - get(TopicPartition) is ambiguous for the type Map<TopicPartition,Object>

Tags: java, apache-kafka

This is my code:

```
    Properties props2 = new Properties();
    props.put(CommonClientConfigs.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(props);
    scala.collection.immutable.Map<TopicPartition,Object> offsets = 
    adminClient.listGroupOffsets("foo");
    Option<Object> offset = offsets.get(new TopicPartition("test", 0));
    System.out.println(Long.parseLong(offset.get().toString()));
```

I am using `kafka_2.11_0.10.2.1` and `kafka-clients_0.10.2.1`. `offsets.get()`  has a compiled problem: `The method get(TopicPartition) is ambiguous for the type Map<TopicPartition,Object>`.How should I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the most optimal way to do it, but it's certainly a workaround.

```
/* import statements */
import org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import kafka.admin.AdminClient;
import scala.collection.JavaConverters;

/* code snippet */
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(CommonClientConfigs.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");

AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(props);
scala.collection.immutable.Map<TopicPartition, Object> offsets =
adminClient.listGroupOffsets("foo");    
Map<TopicPartition, Object> javaOffsets =
JavaConverters.mapAsJavaMapConverter(offsets).asJava();

Object key = javaOffsets.get(new TopicPartition("my-topic", 0));
System.out.println(Long.parseLong(key.toString()));
```